# More Pythonic Way To Do This?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples and I want to convert it to a list of dictionaries where, for each tuple, the dictionary keys are the index in a tuple and the value is the tuple entry in that index.

For example if  `tuple_list=[('a','b','c'), ('e','f','g')]` then the goal is to have `processed_tuple_list = [{0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'},{0:'e',1:'f',2:'g'}]`

My current solution is to have a function

```
def tuple2dict(tup):
    x = {}
    for j in range(len(tup)):
        x[j]=tup[j]
    return x
```

and then call `[tuple2dict(x) for x in tuple_list]`. I suspect there is a list-comprehension way to do this and I initially tried to do

```
[{j:x[j]} for x in tuple_list for j in range(len(x))]
```

but this just gave me a list of `[{0:'a'},{1:'b'},...]`. Any advice on a more pythonic way to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Enumerate is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `dict` for each tuple in `list` like below:

```
>>> tuple_list=[('a','b','c'), ('e','f','g')]
# Expanded solution for more explanation
>>> [{idx: val for idx, val in enumerate(tpl)} for tpl in tuple_list]
[{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, {0: 'e', 1: 'f', 2: 'g'}]
```

By thanks @ddejohn shortest approach:

```
>>> [dict(enumerate(t)) for t in tuple_list]
```

Comment: `[dict(enumerate(t)) for t in tuple_list]` also works

Answer (score 2):

you can use zip
`[dict(zip(range(len(tp)),tp))) for tp in tuple_list]`

Answer (score 1):

Map enumerate into the dictionary constructior for each tuple:

```
processed_tuple_list = [*map(dict,map(enumerate,tuple_list))]

[{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, {0: 'e', 1: 'f', 2: 'g'}]
```